# How to create a list by concatenating two list using python

Tags: python-3.x

How to create a list by concatenating two list using python

```
Var=['Age','Height']
Cat=[1,2,3,4,5]
```

My output should be like this below.

```
AgeLabel=['Age1', 'Age2', 'Age3', 'Age4', 'Age5']
HeightLabel=['Height1', 'Height2', 'Height3', 'Height4', 'Height5']
```

Comment: Check out my recent answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/48412769/901925.  One or two list comprehensions will do the job nicely.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344017/how-can-i-get-the-concatenation-of-two-lists-in-python-without-modifying-either

Answer (score 2):

Combining a [dict comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=comprehension#dictionaries) and a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> labels = 'Age', 'Height'
>>> cats = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
>>> {label: [label + str(cat) for cat in cats] for label in labels}
{'Age': ['Age1', 'Age2', 'Age3', 'Age4', 'Age5'],
 'Height': ['Height1', 'Height2', 'Height3', 'Height4', 'Height5']}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the second list elements as strings concatenate the strings by looping over both the lists. Maintain a dictionary to store the values.

```
Var=['Age','Height']
Cat=[1,2,3,4,5]
label_dict = {}
for i in var:
    label = []
    for j in cat:
         t = i + str(j)
         label.append(t)
    label_dict[i+"Label"] = label
```

at the end label_dict will be

```
  label_dict = {AgeLabel:['Age1', 'Age2', 'Age3', 'Age4', 'Age5'],HeightLabel:['Height1', 'Height2', 'Height3', 'Height4', 'Height5']}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Var=['Age','Height'] 
Cat=[1,2,3,4,5] 
from itertools import product 
print(list(map(lambda x:x[0]+str(x[1]),product(Var,Cat))))
```

This will give you the following output.

```
['Age1', 'Age2', 'Age3', 'Age4', 'Age5', 'Height1', 'Height2', 'Height3', 'Height4', 'Height5']
```

You can split the list as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple and Concise.**

```
Var=['Age','Height']
Cat=[1,2,3,4,5]

AgeLabel = []
HeightLabel= []

for cat_num in Cat:
    current_age_label = Var[0] + str(cat_num)
    current_height_label = Var[1] + str(cat_num)
    AgeLabel.append(current_age_label)
    HeightLabel.append(current_height_label)

print(AgeLabel)
print(HeightLabel)
```

**Output**

```
AgeLabel= ['Age1', 'Age2', 'Age3', 'Age4', 'Age5']
HeightLabel= ['Height1', 'Height2', 'Height3', 'Height4', 'Height5']
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:-**

```
Var=['Age','Height']
Cat=[1,2,3,4,5]
for i in Var:
    c = [(i+str(y)) for y in Cat]
    print (c)  #shows as you expect
```